# What is the best solution for a local AMP stack (web development server)

Tags: wamp, web-development-server

I've started my search with WAMP, then tried out a few others until I settled on UniServer which is a portable AMP stack.

The problem is, I might be working on several web projects at a given time period. The two solutions I've come up with are the following.

1. Have a http.conf file for each project and replace the UniServer http.conf file with the project one whenever I need to work on that project. The only thing that is different with the project http.conf file is the document root folder.
2. Have several copies of UniServer (it's a portable app, which is awesome), one for each project, each with their own http.conf file.

Solution 1 is the most efficient in term of disk space, but is the least convenient since I'd have to manually replace files.

Solution 2 is the most convenient but it seems inefficient since there are copies of the same files everywhere and their only difference is a small http.conf file.

Question 1. I think solution 1 is the most promising. I was wondering if it was possible to automate the file replacing process with one click or so.

Question 2. Perhaps the best solution is completely different from what I described. If so, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Is there something preventing you from just using .htaccess files for the different projects instead of full httpd.conf files?

Comment: Probably not. I forgot to mention that I do not have any training when it comes web server administration. I've always done the bare minimum to get my local server working and haven't really looked into server configuration. I'll look into that .htaccess thing.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I will advise you to use [Varal WAMP.](http://www.VaralWAMP.com) It allows you to create several sites easily from its GUI. You don't need to touch configuration files in Varal WAMP. It does it automatically. Alternatively, you can create virtual hosts for each project.

**Disclosure**: I am the developer of Varal WAMP.

Comment: Will try thanks. In case it isn't already, please consider making it portable?

Comment: Yes, it does work quite nicely. However, unfortunately, I did more research and it looks like my problem is more easily solve by having virtual hosts and assign one per site. No need to even restart my server every time I need to switch.